# (NATIVE JAVASCRIPT) - The function with ajax request does not provide a response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, return-value

I'm currently working in a module where in the user will going to register and the following methods that I'm going to mention will check if the email of the registrant is already in use.

Why is it the function with a ajax request does not return any value to other function with ajax request? By the way, I'm not using any javascript framework such as jquery, just a plain and native javascript ;)

By the way, here is the code ^_^ Note: the XMLHttpRequest() is already okay. Nothing to do with that :)

```
function checkEmailExistense(email){
    var url = "library/functions.php?action=emailchecker&emailadd=" + email;

http.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (http.status == 200 && (http.readyState === 4)){
        var res = http.responseText;
        if (res == "Invalid") {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

http.open("GET", url , true);
http.send();
```

}

On another javascript function wherein I have an ajax request for registration, i have an if statement to check if the returning value of the function above is 0;

```
var emailaddress = document.getElementById("emailadd").value;

if (checkEmailExistense(emailaddress) == 0){
        errorcount+=1;
        errorstatement+="Email already exist";
    }
```

I don't have a problem with my php query, but here is my code ;)

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
switch ($action){
    case 'emailchecker':
        checkTheEmailAdd();
    break;
}

function checkTheEmailAdd(){
    $email = $_GET['emailadd'];

    $connection = new connection();
    $realconnection = $connection->connect();

    $getCount = mysqli_query($realconnection, "SELECT user_email FROM tbl_user WHERE user_email = '".$email."'");


    if(mysqli_num_rows($getCount) > 0){
        echo "Invalid";
    }

}
```

Looking forward for some answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax calls are asynchronous. So you are checking something that isn't there yet.
But even if it wasn't asynchronous, the return statement inside the onreadstatechange handler has no effect on the `checkEmailExistense` method.

Instead use a callback which is invoked as soon as the request returns data:

```
function checkEmailExistense(email, callback){
    var url = "library/functions.php?action=emailchecker&emailadd=" + email;

    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (http.status == 200 && (http.readyState === 4)){
            var res = http.responseText;
            if (res == "Invalid") {
                callback(0);
            } else {
                callback(1);
            }
        }
    }

    http.open("GET", url , true);
    http.send();
}
```

And to check:

```
var emailaddress = document.getElementById("emailadd").value;

checkEmailExistense(emailaddress, function(success) {
    if(success === 0) {
        errorcount+=1;
        errorstatement+="Email already exist";
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I'm going to try the method and update you if there are changes :)

Comment: Also, you might want to escape the email to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Try this: `checkEmailExistense(emailaddress, function(success) {alert(success);});` to verify if you are getting a response.

Comment: Alright, if you are getting any other errors, let me know. Also, as said above, make sure to escape the `$email = mysqli_escape_string($_GET['emailadd'])` because if you don't then people could enter things like `'; DROP ALL TABLES; -- ` as their email address and then the query results in `SELECT user_email FROM tbl_user WHERE user_email = ''; DROP ALL TABLES; -- '` or better, verify if its a valid email http://php.net/manual/de/filter.examples.validation.php

Comment: Noted! Thank you, by the way I noticed that if I include the error message on the javascript variable errorstatement, it does not display the message

Comment: Because it's asynchronous. You probably display the `errorstatement` before the response came in. You can change it to: `checkEmailExistense(emailaddress, function(success) {
    if(success === 0) { /* display error message */ } else { /* hide error message */ }
});`

Comment: Sir, i tried using mysqli_real_escape_string() in getting the email on the url but it performs the same error again, I think there is something wrong with the query after escaping?

Comment: You don't need to call me Sir lol. It's a php function, `$email = mysqli_escape_string($_GET['emailadd']);` but if it doesn't work then just don't do it and use the filter function instead to verif if the email address is valid.

Comment: Thank you haha lol by the way, what are the instances or the signs that the email is invalid using those built-in functions?

Comment: `if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))` runs a huge regexp to check if the format of the email string is  correct and returns either true or false.